# Am I missing a cover in the underbelly of the glove compartment?

Tags: pontiac, vibe

After a service call for a 2003 Vibe, the underbelly of the glove compartment looks like this:
[image: underbelly of glove compartment]

As you see in bottom left of the image, one plug is missing. Also the white mechanical part seems too delicate to have been left exposed at the factory. Did a cover for this section just go missing? If you have an '03 Vibe, could you share a photograph of what you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks normal for a Vibe the only cover should be over the blower motor.

As to the missing plug I believe it's a white or black plastic retainer with a large flange.

I think this is it.

[image]

20478294

Comment: I think there should be one plug holder (don't know what to call it) to hold the carpet up where the diamond is cut into it, though.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 It does look like there is an indent there.